# TikZ node label alignment

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, labels

I started learning TikZ today, and I got to the following image:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,positioning,arrows,shapes.misc,decorations.pathmorphing}

\tikzset{
    >=stealth,
    every picture/.style={thick},
    graphs/every graph/.style={empty nodes},
}

\tikzstyle{vertex}=[
    draw,
    circle,
    fill=black,
    inner sep=1pt,
    minimum width=5pt,
]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
        \graph[ grow right = 2 ] {
            u [vertex, label=$u$]
            --[edge label=$e$]
            v [vertex, label=$v$]
        };
    \end{scope}
    \draw[->,thin] (3,0) -- (5,0) node [midway,above] {subdividing};
    \begin{scope} [xshift=6cm]
        \graph[ grow right = 1 ] {
            u  [vertex, label=$u$]
            -- %[edge label=$e_{uv}$]
            e  [vertex, label=$v_e$]
            -- %[edge label=$e_{vu}$]
            v  [vertex, label=$v$]
        };
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: refinement]

Is there a way to automatically vertically align the `v_e` label with the `u` and `v` in the right graph?

Also, I like the `graph` syntax, but I haven't found an easy way to have it making node labels next to the circle (like in the picture) instead of nodes with the name inside the circle without explicitly using the `label` option.

Comment: You can use `$v\smash{_e}$` in place of `$v_e$`.

Comment: @Kpym, thanks! So it turns out to be a math solution, instead of a TikZ solution, but I think `\smash` (neaver heard of it before) can be used in more general alignment problems.

Comment: You can also use `every node/.append style={text depth=0.5ex},`

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure that `\smash` should be necessary here. It is not needed for the `edge label`s if `anchor` is set to `mid`. However, it does seem to be required for the `node` `label`. But perhaps this is due to my unfamiliarity with the `graphs` library.

You can use the `quotes` library to make it easier to label `edge`s, but I think you still need `label` to label `node`s.

```
\documentclass[border=20pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,quotes,positioning}

\tikzset{
  >=stealth,
  every picture/.style={thick},
  graphs/every graph/.style={empty nodes},
  every edge quotes/.append style={above=7.5pt, anchor=mid, inner sep=0pt},
  every label/.append style={above=2.5pt, anchor=mid, inner sep=0pt},
  vertex/.style={
    draw,
    circle,
    fill=black,
    inner sep=0pt,% doesn't actually change the size and makes it easier to calculate things - or, more accurately, it makes it more obvious how to calculate them
    outer sep=0pt,
    minimum size=5pt,
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph[ grow right = 2 ] {
    u [vertex, label=$u$]
    -- ["$e$"]
    v [vertex, label=$v$]
  };
  \draw (3,0) edge ["subdividing",->,thin] (5,0);
  \begin{scope} [xshift=6cm]
    \graph[ grow right = 1 ] {
      u  [vertex, label=$u$]
      -- ["$e_{uv}$"]
      e  [vertex, label=$v\smash{_e}$]
      -- ["$e_{vu}$"]
      v  [vertex, label=$v$]
    };
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that it does not seem necessary to use `\smash` for the subscript in `$e_{uv}$`.

[image: <code>quotes</code> library, <code>anchor=mid</code> and <code>\smash</code> as last resort]

Comment: The `quotes` library looks useful indeed. I'll look into it tomorrow. Aside, is using `grow right = 2` and `=1` the right way to make the `u` to `v` distance equal in both graphs?

Comment: @Ragnar Sorry, but I don't know. That's a different question and concerns something I know nothing about. I had to look up the manual to follow your syntax ;).

Comment: Well, no one can know the TikZ manual by heart I guess, looking at those 1000+ pages.

Comment: @Ragnar Well, actually, I have to look stuff up all the time. But, in this case, I had to discover that there was a bit of the manual on this to look stuff up in, so I was starting from an earlier point in the learning process ;).